# postgres alias sum

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I'm trying to run a query that structured something like the following in Postgres, But I'm getting and issue with the column sum(). The query doesn't recognize the price alias. How do I achieve this?

```
select col1,
       i2f(....) as col2,
       (select ..... limit 1) as PRICE,
       sum(PRICE +  1)
  from tbl1 a
 where a.".." = 1;
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  column "price" does not exist
LINE 4:            sum(PRICE +  1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use column alias in a subquery, group by or where clause condition.

you should use `WITH` (Common Table Expressions) or use the join command to join the table and use an alias.

```sql
with price as (
 select ..... limit 1
)
select col1,
       i2f(....) as col2,
       sum((select * from price) +  1)
  from tbl1 a
 where a.".." = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: The question you asked is not the only important problem in your SQL.

You also have a general aggregation/GROUP BY problem as well, where some of your SELECT list expressions, in the presence of an aggregate function, are not functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms.  That could use a separate question and answer.

I'll address just your specific question here.

Basically, you're asking about a term in a `<query expression>` called a `<query specification>`, which has the following general form:

```
<query specification> ::=
     SELECT [ <set quantifier> ] <select list> <table expression>
```

Within this is your `<select list>`, which contains, among other things, `<value expression>s`.  These `<value expression>s` may refer to columns of the corresponding `<table expression>`, which does not include any `<derived column>s` in the same `<select list>`.

`(select ..... limit 1) as PRICE` is a `<derived column>` in your `<select list>`, which means `sum(PRICE +  1)` can't refer to this `PRICE`.

There are a few things you can do to allow access to `PRICE`.  Mainly they involve:

1. Deriving PRICE within the corresponding `<table expression>`

That could be contained within a `<derived table>` or a `<table reference>` to a `<with list element>` within a `<with clause>`.

Derived table form:

```sql
SELECT ..., sum(PRICE +  1)
  FROM (
     SELECT ..., expression AS PRICE
       FROM ...
     ) AS tname
...
```

or

WITH clause form:

```sql
WITH tname AS (
     SELECT ..., expression AS PRICE
       FROM ...
     )
SELECT ..., sum(PRICE +  1)
  FROM tname
...
```